# Where tp place data such as images, base64 encoded data for jest tests?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I made a function in Nodejs:

```
const mmm = require('mmmagic');
const mime = require('mime-types');
const {Buffer} = require("node:buffer");

const detectBodyMime = (body,callback) => {
    let buffer = isBase64(body)?Buffer.from(body,'base64'):Buffer.from(body);
  
    const magic = new mmm.Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);

    magic.detect(buffer, function(err, result) {
        
        if (err) {  return callback(err); }

        if(result == 'text/plain') {
            try {
                let text = buffer.toString();
                if (text.codePointAt(0) === 0xFEFF) { // UTF8 BOM
                    text = text.substring(1);
                }
                JSON.parse(text);
                return callback(null,'application/json','json',buffer);
            }catch(e){
                // Do nothing keep it silence we need to just verify that content is Json
            }
        }
        
        return callback(null,result,mime.extension(result),buffer);
    });
}

module.exports={
detectBodyMime
}
```

And I am making some jest tests for it:

```
const {detectBodyMime} = require('../../../src/common/http_utils.js');

test("detectsBase64EncodedImage",(done)=>{
    const content = // Populate data

    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect(mime).toBe('image/jpeg');
        expect(extention).toBe('jpg');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});
```

But in my case I want to populate the:

```
    const content = // Populate data
```

With an image encoded as base64. But If I place the base64 as is will make code unreadable as I place more tests on it. So where/how I can place the image to test, so I can use that as data during the test?

Answer (score 0):

In a seperate JS fixture file (or json file, or even a database).

```
const images = {
  'detectsBase64EncodedImage': 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACAQMAAABIeJ9nAAAABlBMVEUAAP//AADF+ovTAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADElEQVQImWNgYGAAAAAEAAGjChXjAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC',
}

function getTestImage(test_name){
  if (!images[test_name]) throw Error(`No image data for test [${test_name}]`)
  return images[test_name]
}

module.exports = {
  getTestImage,
  images,
}
```

Note that `currentTestName` will include `describe` names as well, but you are free to key the images object with anything.

```
const { getTestImage } = require('./thetests.fixture.js');

test("detectsBase64EncodedImage",(done)=> {
    const content = getTestImage(expect.getState().currentTestName)

    detectBodyMime(content,(err,mime,extention)=>{
        expect(mime).toBe('image/jpeg');
        expect(extention).toBe('jpg');
        expect(err).toBe(null);

        done();
    });
});
```